# Trac wiki page list

Tags: wiki, trac

I create some documentation in the Trac wiki. I set these pages to all start with the same pattern (like "MyDoc...").
I want to retrieve from Trac all the wiki page links for the pages starting with this pattern.

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the `[[TitleIndex]]` macro. See [documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiMacros#TitleIndex-macro). In your example it should be:

```
[[TitleIndex(MyDoc)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How I did it : GET the wiki/TitleIndex page, look for each `<a href="..."/>`, analyze the content of href attribute and if matching my pattern, add the link to the list.

Comment: Seems like you could do this much easier using the TitleIndex macro.  If you did that, you wouldn't need to match the patten, because TitleIndex macro does that for you.  I presume you are trying to get the list in html for use outside of Trac?

Comment: @RjOllos : absolutely, the HTML of the TitleIndex page is processed by some other application.